# file input SWI-Prolog

Tags: file, prolog

Can someone show me the code to read multiply strings from file line by line and print it in console? I can write something to file, but have problems, reading it.
I've tried

1. `see\1`, `seen\0`;
2. `read(Stream, X)`
3. Some predicates found in google, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write something like:

```
read_and_just_print(File) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    repeat,
    read_line_to_codes(Stream, X),
    ( X \== end_of_file -> atom_codes(X1,X),writeln(X1), fail ; close(Stream), ! ).
```